# How to cite when describing a protocol?

Tags: citation

I am writing a paper that involves the description of numerous internet protocols. Because of the rigidity of these protocols, it's difficult for any one description to sound much different from any other. The approach I've taken is to read many descriptions of the protocols, including the official standards, and make an effort to deeply understand the protocols first. Then, without referring to any source, I write out the description of the protocol in the way I understand it and using my own words to describe its operation.

How do I cite something like this? The problem I'm running into is that none of the words or sentences I use are direct quotes from any of my sources. However, the overall structure and description is very similar to all of the sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe would be best handled by having a "References" section at the end, listing the sources you read.  It could include things like

"REQUEST FOR PROPOSAL (RFP) 11168 .......; https://www.wvhepc.org/resources/RFB-RFP/RFP_11168_VoIP/RFP_11168_VoIP_27Mar11_FINAL.pdf"

"RFC 793 - Transmission Control Protocol .......; http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc793.html"

(Where you fill in the "....." with the rest of the long title)